# Повороты в AVL деревьях

Tags: бинарное-дерево

Существует правило, согласно которому можно определить тип поворота. При этом, очень важно, перед определением типа поворота,  определить вершину, в которой нарушился балланс.

При добавлении нового элемента поиск вершины, для которой нарушен баланс AVL дерева (т.е. разница высот поддеревьев в этой вершине больше единицы) осуществляется по пути от нового элемента к корню, т.е. снизу вверх. В каждой вершине при таком подъеме анализируется разница высот поддеревьев.
Когда найдена такая вершина, тогда определяется тип поворота согласно следующего правила:

**LL поворот осуществляется если у левого поддерева выросла левая ветвь.
RR поворот – если у правого поддерева выросла правая ветвь.
RL или LR – если у правого поддерева выросла левая ветвь или у левого поддерва выросла правая ветвь.**

Подскажите пожалуйста поддеревья в данных правилах нужно брать относительно вершины где нарушен баланс или корня дерева? Какой нужен поворот для балансировки дерева приведенного на картинке ниже? То есть в случае как на картинке нужен LR поворот относительно вершины со значением 100?

[image]

Comment: Что значит "поддеревья относительно корня"? Если вы имеете в виду "поддеревья корня" vs. "поддеревья текущей вершины", то, конечно, последнее. Потому поддеревья корня одни и те же, вне зависимости от того, где нарушен баланс, так что вращать их смысла особо нету.

Comment: Вы меня наверное немного не поняли. Я имел ввиду, что при выборе нужного типа поворота в правиле фигурирует такое выражения как поддерево, при проверки припустим RL поворота за поддеревья мне принимать поддеревья корня или поддеревья вершины где нарушен баланс?

Comment: @jeremen1, поддеревья вершины где нарушен баланс.

Посмотрите в [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) все подробно описано.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в Вашем случае нужен **LR** поворот, только для узла *90, а не 100*.

Собственно, при подъеме после вставки узла **93** в левое поддерево узла *95*, Вы обнаружите дисбаланс узла *90*, который после балансировки будет заменен узлом *95* с поддеревьями из узлов 90 и 93.

А у узла *100* никакого дисбаланса при вставке *93* не возникает.

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть нарушение свойства по пути от созданной вершины к корню дерева